# Wald test vs J-test in R

Tags: r, regression

I'm trying to replicate the procedure done in [this link](http://scholar.harvard.edu/files/mankiw/files/permanent_income.pdf) using R. In table 2 it states that column 6 gives the overidentifying restrictions of the IV model using a Wald test. I'm using package *gmm* and I can find a command called *specTest* which makes a J-test. Is this equivalent to the Wald test or how can I implement the Wald test using another package or manually?

Answer (score 1):

As stated: "Column 6 gives the adjusted $R^2$ from a regression of the IV residual onto the Instruments and the significance level for a Wald test of the overidentifying restrictions of the IV model".

You can do this using a customize Wald test function like [this](http://www.utstat.toronto.edu/~brunner/oldclass/appliedf12/lectures/2101f12WaldWithR.pdf).
or functions in R. In this case you will need something like the following code:

```
library(sem)
?tsls
summary(mod1<-tsls(Q ~ P + D, ~ D + F + A, data=Kmenta))     # demand equation
modres<-lm(resid(mod1)~D + F + A, data=Kmenta) # get residuals and regress to instruments
coefs <- names(modres$coefficients)

library(car)
summary(modres)$adj.r.squared
    linearHypothesis(modres, coefs[-1],test="Chisq")$'Pr(>Chisq)'[2]
```